# Use rosparam get in launch file

Tags: roslaunch, rosparam, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am trying to launch a static_transform_publisher from the tf package. It has the following syntax:

```
static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id period_in_ms
```

which should be called from a launch file like this

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 link1_parent link1 100" />
</launch>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to load the parameters `x y z yaw pitch roll` from a calibration (.yaml) file, just as I can  load rosparams using the `rosparam load` syntax:

```
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find rosparam)/example.yaml" />
```

But I can't find a way to use the values from the parameter server and pass them via the `args=` Argument.
I am hoping to find a launchfile-based solution instead of writing a node, that basicaly does the same as the static_transform_publisher node.

Does anyone have a solution?

PS: I do not want to hardcode the values into the launch file, because they might change. Not during runtime, but in between runs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213145/use-rosparam-get-in-launch-file/) by [cbandera](https://answers.ros.org/users/21387/cbandera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-07-08**:
My guess is that this is not possible.

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2015-07-08**:
You may want to edit the source so that those arguments are instead loaded via the parameter server instead of through the launch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just stumbled upon this questions..

I would go for launch file arguments (http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg):

```
<launch>
    <arg name="args" default="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 link1_parent link1 100"/>
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="$(arg args)"/>
</launch>
```

Maybe you should use one argument per parameter.

If you really want to use parameters, you can use this hackish solution that uses bash to append the arguments read by rosparam:

```
<launch>
    <param name="myargs" value="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 link1_parent link1 100"/> <!-- or elsewhere -->
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" launch-prefix="/bin/bash -c '$* `rosparam get myargs`' --"/>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cbandera](https://answers.ros.org/users/21387/cbandera/) on 2015-11-06**:
Hi, thanks for your replay. I will test this next time.
In the meantime, I have written my own "static_transform_publisher_node" which is able to accept rosparams, and can even read from our custom file format. So this solved it for me.

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2017-01-09**:
It seems that the second hack doesn't work for me (ros indigo)

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2017-01-14**:
I have just run a test on kinetic and it works. And I am pretty sure I have tested it with indigo as well..

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2017-01-16**:
Sorry, I just retried and it work. I don't know what was my test. Even the param overwrite work. Thx

**Comment by [Chrisando](https://answers.ros.org/users/28589/chrisando/) on 2017-01-26**:
This hackish solution works for me. How can I use it with a namespace? For example get /"namespace"/sensor_pos_0`' <group ns="tower_0"> <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"  name="sensor_pose_0" launch-prefix="/bin/bash -c '$*` rosparam get /tower_0/sensor_pos_0`' --"/>

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2017-01-27**:
rosparam retrieve its data relative the to namespace of the .
`rosparam get /tower_0/param` should work as well as `rosparam get param`.
Please do not name your parameter the same as your node as it turns `sensor_pos_0` into a namespace.

**Comment by [Chrisando](https://answers.ros.org/users/28589/chrisando/) on 2017-01-27**:
Thank you @Mathias Lüdtke I works as you said.